# yytext contains characters not in match

Tags: regex, string, match, flex-lexer, lex

## Background

I am using *flex* to generate a lexer for a programming language I am implementing.

I have some problems with this rule for identifiers:

```
[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]* {
    printf("yytext is %s\n", yytext);    
    yylval.s = yytext;
    return TOK_IDENTIFIER;
}
```

The rule works as it should when my parser is parsing expressions like this:

```
var0 = var1 + var2;
```

The `printf` statement will print out this:

```
yytext is 'var0'
yytext is 'var1'
yytext is 'var2'
```

Which is what it should.

## The problem

But when my parser is parsing function declarations like this one:

```
func(array[10] type, arg2 wef, arg3 afe);
```

Now the `printf` statement will print this:

```
yytext is 'array['
yytext is 'arg2 wef'
yytext is 'arg3 afe'
```

The problem is that `yytext` contains characters that are not in the match.

## Question

Why does *flex* include these characters in `yytext` and how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see how that output could be produced from your lexer, but it is easy to see how it could be produced in your parser.

Basically, it is not correct to retain the value of `yytext`:

```
yylval.s = yytext;  /* DON'T DO THIS */
```

In effect, that is a dangling pointer because `yytext` is pointing to private memory inside the lexer framework, and the pointer is only valid until the next time the lexer is called. Since the parser generally needs to look at the next input token before executing a reduction action, it is almost certain that the pointer in the `s` member of each terminal in the production will have been invalidated by the time the action is executed.

If you want to keep the string value of the token pointed to by `yytext`, you must copy it:

```
yylval.s = strdup(yytext);
```

and then you will be responsible for freeing the copy when you no longer need it.

Comment: This could very well have been the problem but it is not the case.  I have the `strdup` code in my parser to avoid this problem. 

The output I describe comes directly from the `printf` statement in the code example. I have no idea what is wrong but `yytext` is wrong immediately after a rule is matched. There is no code in between.

Comment: Ahhh! I see. The problem was that I had the `strdup` code in the parser. Because the parser needs to read one token forward the next also gets included in the string before I `strdup` it!

Thank you. This helped me solve my problem.