# Shift Reduce Conflict in Bison Grammar

Tags: parsing, bison

I have just started working with Bison and I am facing a couple of issues. The goal of my grammar is to recognize a "command pipeline" language where the output of one command can be piped as the input of another command. Each command can also have a list of parameters with an optional value. Here is an example:

```
command1 --param1 test --param2 test2 | command2 | command3 --param3
```

In the previous example, `command1` takes two parameters, `param1` with value `test` and `param2` with value `test2`. The output of `command1` is then "piped" to `command2`, which takes no parameters. Finally the result of `command2` is piped to `command3`, which takes one parameter (parameters with no value are considered as a switch).

The corresponding bison grammar is given below:

```
%{

#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "AST.h"
#include "Evaluator.h"

void yyerror (const char *error);
int  yylex();

%}

%code{
    Evaluator eval;
}

%union {
  char* s;
  double d;
  AbstractNode* abstractnode;
  CmdletCall* cmdletdef;
  ParameterDef* parameterdef;
  ParameterListDef* paramlistdef;
}

/* declare tokens */

%token EOL
%token<s> PARAMETERNAME
%token<s> BUILTIN
%token<s> IDENTIFIER


%type <parameterdef> parameterDef
%type <cmdletdef> cmdletCall
%type <abstractnode> pipeLineDef    
%type <paramlistdef> paramList
%%

input: /* nothing */
    | input pipeLineDef EOL {
                                $2->accept(eval);
                                delete $2;
                                std::cout << eval.result() << std::endl;
                            }                        
    | input EOL             {}
    ;



pipeLineDef: cmdletCall                  {$$ = $1;}      
    | pipeLineDef '|' cmdletCall         {$$ = new PipeLineDef($1, $3);}   
    ;


cmdletCall: IDENTIFIER                   {$$ = new CmdletCall($1);}                 
          | cmdletCall paramList         {$1->setParameterList($2);}   
          ;

paramList: parameterDef                 {  
                                            $$ = new ParameterListDef;
                                            $$->addChildNode($1);
                                        }  
         | paramList parameterDef       {
                                            $1->addChildNode($2);
                                            $$ = $1;
                                        }
         ;

parameterDef: PARAMETERNAME             {$$ = new ParameterDef($1);}
            | parameterDef IDENTIFIER   {
                                            $1->setValue($2);
                                        }         

            ;




%%


void yyerror (const char *error)
{
  std::cout << error << std::endl;
}
```

The previous grammar has one shift-reduce conflict, which is reproduced below:

```
Terminals unused in grammar

BUILTIN

State 10 conflicts: 1 shift/reduce
State 10

7 cmdletCall: cmdletCall paramList .
9 paramList: paramList . parameterDef

PARAMETERNAME  shift, and go to state 9

PARAMETERNAME  [reduce using rule 7 (cmdletCall)]
$default       reduce using rule 7 (cmdletCall)

parameterDef  go to state 13
```

I would like to remove the conflict but I am not sure how I should proceed (my understanding is that a shift/reduce conflict indicates an ambiguous grammar). However, from my initial tests, everything seems to work as expected.
Another point that puzzles me is the way Bison evaluates the terminals. For example, if I rewrite the `cmdletCall` and `paramList` rules as follows, the grammar breaks:

```
cmdletCall: IDENTIFIER paramList         {$$ = new CmdletCall($1);    $$->setParameterList($2);}   
          ;

paramList: /*nothing*/ 
                                        {  
                                            $$ = new ParameterListDef;

                                        }  
         | paramList parameterDef       {
                                            $1->addChildNode($2);
                                            $$ = $1;
                                        }
         ;
```

If I rewrite the grammar as shown above, then for an input such as:

```
command1 --param1
```

In the `cmdletCall` rule, The value of `$1`, which corresponds to the `IDENTIFIER` token, will be `command1 --param1`, instead of `command1` only.

Comment: Although C (or optionally C++) is the language for which bison generates code, this question isn't actually about either of those.  Tags edited.

Comment: That's two separate problems, which should be two separate questions. The second question almost certainly involves your lexer (and in some sense, the C/C++ code therein), although I'd suggest you just search for the need to copy yytext in your lexer; it's in all the faqs.

Comment: Keeping the second question as part of this same question because it illustrates the kind of issues you can have using bison and flex in practice. And since you have given the answer to both questions it makes sense to keep them together :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your definition of `cmdletCall` is effectively `IDENTIFIER paramList*` (using the standard regular-language Kleene star operator). But `paramList` is `paramDef+`. So that's clearly ambiguous; there is no way to tell how many `paramList`s follow the `IDENTIFIER` because there is no indication where one ends and the next one begins.

In fact, you want to have only (or at most) one `paramList`. There are several options, but the simplest is:

```
cmdletCall: IDENTIFIER paramList
paramList : /* empty */
          | paramList parameterDef
```

Another option would be to keep `paramList` non-nullable, and add a `cmdletCall` option which consists only of an `IDENTIFIER`. Really, that's only useful if you need to separate the cases for a semantic rule, but is certainly possible.

Or for an even simpler grammar, just get rid of `paramList`:

```
cmdletCall: IDENTIFIER
          | cmdletCall parameterDef
```

Since bison-generated parsers prefer shift to reduce, the parser produced from your ambiguous grammar will do what you expect: only produce zero or one `paramList` for each command. But you would be well advised to eliminate the ambiguity anyway.

---

The problem you had with the associated semantic value is the result of not copying the contents of `yytext` from your scanner; `yytext` is an internal datastructure in the flex-built scanner, and its contents do not belong to you, since the scanner can and will modify them as it sees fit.

Comment: So you mean that in the flex scanner, I need to copy the contents of yytext? At the moment I have always been doing something like yylval.s = yytext.

Comment: @BigLudinski: Yes, and the question comes up over and over again. Here's a recent answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33878874/1566221 , and here's one from a couple of years ago: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13166741/1566221 As I said, it's in all the FAQs, including the bison FAQ

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the enlightment! I spent most of New-Year's Eve going nuts on this. I modified the grammar as you suggested and this resolved the shift/reduce conflict. I also made a private copy of the contents of yytext using yylval.s = strdup(yytext) and now everything works perfectly! I still need to get memory management right but thanks to you I am on the right track :)

Comment: @BigLudinski: Cool. My guess is that in your simple case, you can just `free` the string copies in the destructor of `AbstractNode`, but for complete resilience against parsing errors, you'll also want to define `%destructor` functions so that bison can know how to free memory from semantic values it pops off the stack during error handling. Here's another SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31105408/1566221 . I keep thinking I should collect all this stuff in one place.